# Explain how this sql syntax works from Access in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an access database that I am converting to SQL Server and there is a report that has the follow:

```
SELECT tblInventoryUnit.[ORG-IU],
   tblInventoryUnit.[Parent ORG Name],
   tblVehicle.[Asset Tag Number],
   tblVehicle.[Vehicle Unit Type],
   tblVehicle.[Historical Unit Number],
   tblVehicle.[License Plate Number],
   tblVehicle.[Model Year],
   tblVehicle.Make,
   tblVehicle.Model,
   tblVehicle.[Acquisition Date],
   tblVehicle.[Vehicle Cost],
   tblVehicle.[Insurance Account],
   tblVehicle.[Insurance Sub-Account],
   tblVehicle.[Project Code],
   tblFSOTeams.[Fund Accountant Team],
   tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]
FROM tblSPSTeams
    RIGHT JOIN(tblFSOTeams
    INNER JOIN(tblInventoryUnit
    INNER JOIN tblVehicle
        ON tblInventoryUnit.[ORG-IU] = tblVehicle.[ORG-IU]) 
        ON tblFSOTeams.[Org Number] = tblInventoryUnit.[Parent ORG])
        ON tblSPSTeams.[Account Number] = tblVehicle.[Insurance Account]
WHERE (
          ((tblVehicle.[Vehicle Unit Type]) <> 'TA')
          AND ((tblVehicle.[Acquisition Date]) < '7/15/2020')
          AND
          (
              (tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Pending - Motor Pool'
              OR (tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Active - In Use'
              OR (tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Active - Unlocated'
              OR (tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Active - Surplused'
          )
          AND ((tblSPSTeams.[SPS Team Number]) IS NULL)
      )
      OR
      (
          ((tblVehicle.[Vehicle Unit Type]) <> 'TA')
          AND ((tblVehicle.[Acquisition Date]) < '7/15/2020')
          AND ((tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Inactive')
          AND ((tblSPSTeams.[SPS Team Number]) IS NULL)
          AND ((tblVehicle.[Disposal Date]) > '7/1/2020')
      );
```

I have figured out from looking at the diagram that this equals:

```
SELECT tblInventoryUnit.[ORG-IU],
   tblInventoryUnit.[Parent ORG Name],
   tblVehicle.[Asset Tag Number],
   tblVehicle.[Vehicle Unit Type],
   tblVehicle.[Historical Unit Number],
   tblVehicle.[License Plate Number],
   tblVehicle.[Model Year],
   tblVehicle.Make,
   tblVehicle.Model,
   tblVehicle.[Acquisition Date],
   tblVehicle.[Vehicle Cost],
   tblVehicle.[Insurance Account],
   tblVehicle.[Insurance Sub-Account],
   tblVehicle.[Project Code],
   tblFSOTeams.[Fund Accountant Team],
   tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]
FROM dbo.tblVehicle
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblSPSTeams
        ON dbo.tblVehicle.[Insurance Account] = dbo.tblSPSTeams.[Account Number]
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblInventoryUnit
        ON tblInventoryUnit.[ORG-IU] = tblVehicle.[ORG-IU]
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblFSOTeams
        ON tblFSOTeams.[Org Number] = dbo.tblInventoryUnit.[Parent ORG]
WHERE (
          ((tblVehicle.[Vehicle Unit Type]) <> 'TA')
          AND ((tblVehicle.[Acquisition Date]) < '7/15/2020')
          AND
          (
              (tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Pending - Motor Pool'
              OR (tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Active - In Use'
              OR (tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Active - Unlocated'
              OR (tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Active - Surplused'
          )
          AND ((tblSPSTeams.[SPS Team Number]) IS NULL)
      )
      OR
      (
          ((tblVehicle.[Vehicle Unit Type]) <> 'TA')
          AND ((tblVehicle.[Acquisition Date]) < '7/15/2020')
          AND ((tblVehicle.[Vehicle Status]) = 'Inactive')
          AND ((tblSPSTeams.[SPS Team Number]) IS NULL)
          AND ((tblVehicle.[Disposal Date]) > '7/1/2020')
      );
```

Can someone explain how the first query works? I don't get the syntax. In particular, this part:

```
FROM tblSPSTeams
RIGHT JOIN(tblFSOTeams
INNER JOIN(tblInventoryUnit
INNER JOIN tblVehicle
    ON tblInventoryUnit.[ORG-IU] = tblVehicle.[ORG-IU]) 
    ON tblFSOTeams.[Org Number] = tblInventoryUnit.[Parent ORG])
    ON tblSPSTeams.[Account Number] = tblVehicle.[Insurance Account]
```

It looks like two subqueries but there is no select statement in the inner tables. I tried to add a select statement like a "normal" subquery but it balked at the idea. How exactly does this work? Is there a special syntax that I am not getting?

Comment: MS Access requires parentheses around `JOIN`s in the `FROM` (when there is more than one `JOIN`).  Other databases support such grouping but do not require it.

Comment: `FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON t3... ON t2...` is the same as a derived table `FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 JOIN t3 ON t3...) t2 ON t2...` By the way, `tblSPSTeams` should probably be a `NOT EXISTS` anyway